# Why $T_{\alpha}:T^*X\to T^*X$ is a diffeomorphism? With $\alpha$ not necessarily a closed form.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I wanna know why if $\alpha$ a 1-form on $X$, then the next map is a diffeomorphism.

$$T_{\alpha}:T^*X\to T^*X$$
$$\hspace{2.4cm}\beta \mapsto \beta + \alpha_{\pi(\beta)} $$

I know if $\alpha$ is a closed form then the map is a symplectic diffeomorphism, and if $\alpha$ isn't closed it isn't symplectic, but it is a diffeomorphism. I saw some info in this question [Coordinate-free proof of non-degeneracy of symplectic form on cotangent bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787544/coordinate-free-proof-of-non-degeneracy-of-symplectic-form-on-cotangent-bundle) but I really don't catch it.

Comment: Which part of the definition of diffeomorphism are you having trouble verifying?

Comment: I've been trying to check that the map has an inverse $T_{\alpha}^{-1} that is C^{\infty}, but I don't even know how to define it

Comment: (If you want me to be notified, you have to type @Jason somewhere in your comment).  What if you just focus on one cotangent space?  Can you define the inverse there?

Comment: Tangentially-related question for you: Do you understand why the graph of *any* smooth function $f\colon X\to Y$ (as a submanifold of $X\times Y$) is diffeomorphic to $X$?

Comment: That's really more of a cotangentially related question ;).

Comment: *smacks @Jason*

Comment: Guys, I understand the idea with the graph, I can use the projection to prove that. But with $T_{\alpha}$ I don't see how to use it. I've been trying to see how it works in each fiber, but really I don't know how to define the inverse. @JasonDeVito

Comment: @Luis:  Say the fiber is $2$-dimensional, just to pick a nice concrete number.  Then the cotangent space at a point is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an isomorphism taking $\alpha_{\pi(p)}$ to some vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and then $T_\alpha$ is identified with the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x)=x+v$.  (If it helps, pick a concrete vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$).  What does adding $v$ do geometrically?  What's the inverse of that?